# Como serializar um dateTime exibindo no formato dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net

Como faço para enviar para `View()` da minha Controller no formato Json, a data formatada no padrão `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`?

No transporte dos dados entre View e Controller estou utilizando AJAX.

```
public ActionResult GetList(Object abc) {

...

ObjEntity temp = methodGetInDB();

 string valueJson =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(temp);

//Saída temp: "Date":"\/Date(1483290061000)\/"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma saída seria converter o DateTime para string formatada e depois devolver para view como json.

Ex: `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: existe outras formas como no post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: Valeu pela indicação, funcionou muito bem aqui !!!  
=)